# Removing duplicates in R

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

I have a large dataset (>37 m individuals) and I am using R. I am very much a beginner. Currently, I'm trying (and trying, and trying) to calculate the average household size per Province in the Country that I am analyzing. I have managed to create a separate data frame, with the required variables to give an individual number to each person and thus a household number under the variable called HH (for HouseHolds). Now I want R to remove the duplicates from this specific column in the new data frame that I created, i.e. the HH column.

I have tried numerous times using the duplicate() and unique() functions but it does not work. I've also tried to isolate the this "HH" column in a separate sheet but these functions does still not remove the duplicates. I've also tried converting it into a vector and then doing the duplicate() and unique() functions (as you can see beneath).

When I use a smaller sample in excel it works perfectly well (asking excel to remove the duplicates).

This is how I created my dataset based on my initial dataset (i.e. PHCKCON):

```
HHvars<-c("eano", "county", "tif")
HHKE<-PHCKCON[HHvars]
as.numeric(HHKE$county)
HHKE$county<-as.numeric(HHKE$county)
```

Then I created an 4th column for my Households:

```
HHKE$HH<-(paste(HHKE$eano, HHKE$county, HHKE$tif))
```

Here is an example of my dataset:
[The values in the first three columns are numeric whilst the last are classified as characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eB4Q.png)

Here is a small sample of the data (I invented these but same idea):

```
Enumeration.area    County    Household.members
1                   a         4
1                   a         4 
1                   a         6
1                   a         6
1                   a         8
1                   a         8
1                   a         8
2                   a         4
2                   a         4
2                   a         6
1                   b         6
1                   b         6
1                   b         8 
1                   b         8
1                   b         12
1                   b         12
1                   b         12
1                   b         12
```

And here is what I did to create my 4th column called HH:

```
mydata$HH<-paste(mydata$Enumeration.area, mydata$County, mydata$Household.members)
```

It then gives a fourth column.

```
HH
1 a 4
1 a 4
1 a 6
1 a 6
1 a 8
1 a 8
1 a 8
1 a 8
2 a 4
2 a 4
2 a 6
2 a 8
1 b 6
1 b 6
1 b 8 
1 b 8
1 b 12
1 b 12
1 b 12
1 b 12
```

Then I created a separate dataset for my HH column (in order to duplicate):

```
attach(mydata)
HHvars<-c("HH")
EX2<-mydata[HHvars]
```

I then tried to duplicate EX2, HH colum:

```
EX2[!duplicated(EX2$HH),]
```

But it is not working. And not when using the

```
unique()
```

function either.

I hope that it is clearer! And still grateful for any help.

Cheers,
Madeleine

Comment: So what are you trying to do exactly? Could you give an example of the output you are trying for? And could you clarify what that variables in your columns represent?

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain this... The end result that I want is for R to tell me the average household size. At the moment, R is not summarizing all the same answers.

Comment: Post some example input with proper column names and the example output you want. You can construct this small input/output data in R yourself and post as an edit to your question. That is the best way to get help.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain this... The end result that I want is for R to be able to calculate the mean and the median household size per Province (9) and in total there are 47 Counties. To do so, I have to create a household identify column. I used "concatenate" for this in excel and similar in R. 
The 1st 3 variables represent "enumeration area number"; "county number" and; "tif" stands for the individual members of each household. And "HH" is the household identity and the column that I need to calculate the average HH size. But for this, I need to remove the duplicates.

Comment: I added some data sample and tried to explain the issue a bit better

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking for is simply the mean and median for each county of each enumeration.area, you can do this rather quickly using `dplyr`. I made up some data below to somewhat match yours.

```
library(dplyr)
HH <- data.frame(
    Enumeration.area=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    County=c('a','a','b','a','a','a','b','a','b'),
    Household.members=c(4,6,5,8,10,9,3,4,3)
)
HH %>% group_by(Enumeration.area,County) %>% summarise(mean=mean(Household.members),median=median(Household.members))
```

Which results in:

```
     Enumeration.area County  mean median
                (dbl) (fctr) (dbl)  (dbl)
1                1      a     5      5
2                1      b     5      5
3                2      a     9      9
4                3      a     4      4
5                3      b     3      3
```

Then each row of the resulting data set is a unique combination of Enumeration.area and County, and for each of those combinations you'll have your mean and median household numbers.

**edit:**

Since your desired output is regarding creating a concatenated identifier for each observation, this is how you could do that:

```
df <- HH %>% group_by(Enumeration.area,County) %>% 
  mutate(id=paste(Enumeration.area,County,Household.members))
```

This will create a character string that is the combination of Enumeration.area, County, and Household.members. Then using `distinct(id)` will remove any duplicates, as shown below:

```
df
  Enumeration.area County Household.members     id
              (dbl) (fctr)             (dbl)  (chr)
1                1      a                 4  1 a 4
2                1      a                 6  1 a 6
3                1      b                 5  1 b 5
4                2      a                 8  2 a 8
5                2      a                10 2 a 10
6                2      a                 9  2 a 9
7                3      b                 3  3 b 3
8                3      a                 4  3 a 4
9                3      b                 3  3 b 3

df %>% distinct(id)
  Enumeration.area County Household.members     id
             (dbl) (fctr)             (dbl)  (chr)
1                1      a                 4  1 a 4
2                1      a                 6  1 a 6
3                1      b                 5  1 b 5
4                2      a                 8  2 a 8
5                2      a                10 2 a 10
6                2      a                 9  2 a 9
7                3      b                 3  3 b 3
8                3      a                 4  3 a 4
```

As you can see, the duplicate row "3 b 3" has now just been reduced to one unique observation.

Comment: Thank you for this! But the thing is that I have 200 enumeration areas, 47 counties and a very large amount of household members. Is there a function or code in R that I can use that gathers all the codes / variable? In particular the household.members variables. In the database, they go up to 156 (3rd quartile) and the max is at 814.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't quite understand what you are asking for. I notice in an earlier comment you want to incorporate Province, but I don't see that varaible anywhere in your data set. If you are interested in obtaining the mean/median of groups of data, using some type of aggregate function is going to be the easiest way to do so. I will edit my post to address your desired output.

Comment: Thank you! This makes more sense to me. I will try do to it this way.